# Can we modify gov registry values from Proxy Services WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, global-variables, esb

I want to set some Global Variables using my Proxy service which I can check/modify from different threads when my proxy service is called.

Comment: You might want to share some details concerning configuration or example code you are using in your attempt to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi, actually I am picking up messages from a queue but my backend service only allows one message per session. 
I am using Message Sampling Processor but setting the concurrency to 1 there doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You're consuming events from a queue (message store) and you want to send events from this queue to an endpoint one by one? Did you try the Message Forwarding Processor? (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+702%3A+Introduction+to+Message+Forwarding+Processor)

Comment: I cant you message forwading processor, because I need to make some transformations in the message before sending it...
These changes are to be done on the fly and I cannot make these transformations before hand and then save it in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a bit vague, but it seems what you're looking for are properties with 'Syanpse' scope, where they will be exposed to both in and out sequences.

Comment: No, what I want is some kind of 'lock' that I could use on the different service threads being spawned.  Kind of an Hold and wait type.